# Can't view iCloud Files from iPhone

Tags: file, encryption, icloud, desktop, icloud-drive

I have issue with my iCloud drive files. Desktop and documents aren't showing on my iPhone. I've looked in my iCloud settings and it says encrypted. Other things like Pages and Keynote works. Any Ideas how to solve it? It is showing white screen and no errors

Comment: What do you mean "Not Showing"? Is there an error? White screen? Is the file actually supported? What happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've contacted Apple support and found out that it can't complete downloading files from iCloud. It was because I didn't have enough space on my iPhone. I had to free up space in iPhone.